# delay Problem switching tab with xml in it

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

i have app that parser xml from my blog and i have UItabbar and UItableview in it.
in each tab i fetch XML from different site.
the problem is when i click to the second tab it take 1-2 sec and then go to the second tab in the 1-2 sec its load the xml...
how do i make it go first to the second tab and then load the xml?
my project : [Click](http://www.mediafire.com/?bl45e6226oectc9)
if you can edit my project it will be awesome :D 
tnx
diabolo

Answer (score 0):

You should call the function which loads the xml  like this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(yourFunctionName) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
```

You can increase the delay, I have entered 1 here but you can change it.

Comment: it doesnt work... can you please check this code in my project?

Comment: @ok I will do that and send u the updated code, but right now i m quite busy! Sorry

Comment: NP TNX if you can send if to 22diabolo@gmail.com it will be awesome :)

Comment: Harsh can you please send me the project? tnx

Comment: @user535351: Your updated code is ready, please inform me when u r ready to accept that. I will send u the mail.

Comment: OK Tomorrow I will send u the code, if that works for u then please dont forget to accept the answer.

Comment: @user535351: I have sent u the code on ur Email, please check and confirm.